# Reload whole react app on specific change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a responsive application and currently, I have a problem with reloading the whole app.

What do I want? 
Then the user resizes the window, I want to reload the whole app, all components, instead of reloading just one component.

Tried with pushing the new route, though it could rerender all application, but it won't.

```
const HIDE_DRAWER_AT = 500;
if(window.innerWidth < HIDE_DRAWER_AT) {
      this.setState({ openDrawer: false, drawerAction: true });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ openDrawer: true, drawerAction: true });
    }

// here need to rerender whole application.
```

Comment: why dont you set state in the root component on the window.resize event

Comment: actually i tried, 
`window.addEventListener("resize", () => this.redrawDrawer());`
and in redrawDrawer() i changing state, but it only rerender just app component, but not whole tree.

Comment: Because on comparison with the virtual dom there is no change in the rest of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I made this up for you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zq1jp12wlx

App will check the window width and change the value if the browser is resized. It will then pass the new value as a prop so Drawer can handle the display logic.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.getWidth.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.getWidth.bind(this));
  }

  getWidth() {
    this.setState({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Drawer width={this.state.windowWidth} />;
  }
}

export default class Drawer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Drawer">
        {this.props.width < 500 ? (
          <h3>I'm the drawer! DESKTOP.</h3>
        ) : (
          <h3>I'm the drawer! MOBILE.</h3>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```